# I don't know how to post data from rich text field to ms access rows

Tags: c#

I successfully posted the formatted string to access database but the strings are not inserted into the rows instead they all lined up in one row.

```
    private void viewLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
    {     
        string status = this.statusDisplay.Text;
        string time = this.logtimeDispaly.Text;
        try
        {
            for (int rows = 0; rows < status.Length; rows++)
            {
                //create a new connection
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = ElevatorStatusLog.mdb");
                //open the connection
                connection.Open();
                //create a query
                OleDbCommand command;
                command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO StatusLog([DateTime],[Activities]) VALUES(@Parameter1, @Parameter2)", connection);
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Parameter1", time.ToString()));
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Parameter2", status.ToString()));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }    

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
        }
```

This should have been inserted into the rows instead. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Does it throws any exceptions?

Comment: No it doesn't. It works but not rightly. About 4 lines of strings from the rich text in inserted into one row in access. That's  why I tried using the for loop to correct this.

Comment: Is the MDB File inside your project?

Comment: Yes it is in the Debug folder.

Comment: if your MDB files is being copied every time you build your project it will reset its value, is not that?

Comment: 5/12/2014 15:48:535/12/2014 15:48:545/12/2014 15:48:54 (in DateTime row) and User requests @ Floor 0User going to Floor1User arrives @ Floor 1 (shows like this in Activities column) instead of each data in seperate rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I got help from a senior school mate. And I hope it helps a student in future because I couldn't find a straight-forward solution online.

```
private void viewLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
           if(statusDisplay.Lines.Count() > 1){
                var total = statusDisplay.Lines.Count()-1;
                for (int c = 0; c < total; c++)
                {

                    //create a new connection
                    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = ElevatorStatusLog.mdb");
                    //open the connection
                    connection.Open();
                    //create a query
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO StatusLog([DateTime],[Activities]) VALUES(@Parameter1, @Parameter2)", connection);
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Parameter1", this.logtimeDispaly.Lines.ElementAt(c).ToString()));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Parameter2", this.statusDisplay.Lines.ElementAt(c).ToString()));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
        }
```